# PdfBox Error "Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font" when render image from pdf

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have tried to render image from image by using method renderImage of PDFRenderer. This work in local, but failed in Server Environment:

```
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.082+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Times-Roman","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.085+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Times-Bold","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.088+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Times-Italic","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.090+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Times-BoldItalic","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.092+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Helvetica","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.094+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Helvetica-Bold","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.096+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Helvetica-Oblique","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.098+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Helvetica-BoldOblique","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.100+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Courier","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.102+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Courier-Bold","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.103+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Courier-Oblique","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.105+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Courier-BoldOblique","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.147+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Symbol","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.149+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font ZapfDingbats","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-08-08T16:52:11.150+07:00","level":"WARN","logger_name":"org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font","message":"Using fallback font LiberationSans for Helvetica-Bold","thread_name":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1"}
```

Here is my code:

```
PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(pdfBytes);
PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(pdDocument);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = pdfRenderer.renderImage(0, 6).getSubimage(57, 1420, 1164, 424);
pdDocument.close();
```

My pdfbox version: 2.0.26

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.26</version>
</dependency>
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Install the missing fonts on that system `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. The ZapfDingbats font you'll have to buy or get elsewhere.

Comment: @Jay, Is that issue resolved for you? Because I'm also facing the issue in my project. Its working in my local, but I could see this same warnings in other environments. Please suggest me If you found any solution for this. Thanks